# How do I use one of the model's fields as one of the limits in a range query on itself?

Tags: django, database

I have a model defined in Django as such

```
model TempModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField()
    bar = models.IntegerField()
```

One of my queries is structured as

```
Q(bar__range=(lower_limit, upper_limit))
```

However, I want to use the value in my foo field as the lower_limit. I tried using F objects for the same

```
from django.db.models import Q, F

Q(bar__range=(F('foo'), upper_limit)
```

However, this gave me an error:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'F'
```

What can I do instead to use my foo field value as one of the limits?